# Would there be a split between ZFC and FC in a type-I superconductor?

Tags: superconductivity

I am trying to understand why there is a split between ZFC and FC in superconductors. I found an answer that suggests that [some flux remains in the superconductor after cooling](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/167369/what-kinds-of-behavioural-anomalies-can-a-zero-field-cooled-zfc-field-cooled). However, according to my textbook, a type-I superconductor should have no flux. So, would there be a split between ZFC and FC in a type-I superconductor, or is there something wrong with my understanding?